# BlueImp File Upload "Error: Method Not Allowed" - Laravel 4 Routing Issue

Tags: jquery, file-upload, laravel-4, routes, blueimp

I am using [Blueimp.jquery file-upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html) for file uploads. My app is also under `Laravel 4` framework and I have an error on uploading file. 
The error returned by this `API` in Firefox and Chrome is:

```
 Error: Method Not Allowed
```

I think the error comes with `routing` on `Laravel` because this is what I found on `Firebug` dev console:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException","message":"","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\digisells\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php","line":210}}
```

This is the form code:

```
{{ Form::open(['route'=>'image.store','id'=>'fileupload','files'=>true]) }}
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- file upload -->
     <!-- <form id="fileupload" action="file-upload/product-images" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> -->
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="thumbnail" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-md-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
<!--     </form> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ Form::close() }}
```

This is the `routes` code for the form:

```
Route::resource('image', 'ImageUploadController');
```

And inside the `ImageUploadController` I have:

```
public function store()
    {
        $file = Input::file('thumbnail');
        $file = move(public_path().'/product/images/temp/', $file=>getClientOriginaLName());
    }
```

If the `routing` is the issue, How could I register these `routes` on my `routes` file? I mean what verbs do I have to use and the codes inside of each functions? Or are there some other possible solutions to this? Thanks.

Comment: Probably more helpful if you post your current route handling the upload and also the relevant controller action

Answer (score 2):

I also had that error with Blueimp.jquery file-upload + Laravel 4. I solved it by adding a route for my Ajax call with PUT method. (even though jquery-file-upload is said to use POST [in their documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#type))

My route looks like this:

```
Route::put('upload/image', array('as' => 'admin.upload', 'uses' => 'App\Controllers\Admin\ImageController@postUpload'));
```

javascript call:

```
$('.image-upload').fileupload({
url: '/upload/image',
dataType: 'JSON',
//type: 'POST',
done: function (e, data) {
    //console.log(data);
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo($('.image-placeholder'));
    });
}
});
```

**EDIT:**

After some further testing I found out that if I add additional 'data.formData' to my request (as described [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#submit)), it will use a POST method instead of PUT...

Answer (score 0):

MethodNotAllowedHttpException generally means that the method you are using to call that URL is incorrect.

Assuming this error is happening when you are trying to upload a file, then it could just be a case of changing that Route to be a POST route instead of a GET route.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to change the `method` with GET or POST. But either way, same error returns.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
$('.image-upload').fileupload({
    url: '/upload/image',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    method: 'POST',
    done: function (e, data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo($('.image-placeholder'));
        });
    }
});
```

Then you'll receive csrf error which can be fixed adding csrf-field ... check here:
[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)