# Is it possible to return an array object back to the same view from a method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am very new to Laravel and hence I'm trying to put together my first Laravel Web Application. However, I have become a little stuck on the following scenario:

I have a page that requests a file input and has a process button. After selecting a file and clicking process, I route to `ConversionController@evaluateFile` to process information about the file. Within this method I build an array `$file` which I want to return back to the original view (home) to show the file details at the top of the page.  I also want to show an animation whilst the file is being evaluated.

Currently I am trying this:
`return view( 'home' )->with( 'file', $file );` at the end of my controller which looks as though it returns me back to the same view, but nothing appears within my blade variables. If I simply return the array by using `return $file` I can see that the array is properly populated.

My view has the following code to accommodate the array:

```
@if( ! empty( $file->name ) )

    <p>{{ $file->name }}</p>
    <hr>

@endif
```

I also have the following routes assigned:

```
Route::get( 'home', 'ConversionController@index' );
Route::post( 'home', 'ConversionController@evaluateFile' );

Route::post( 'process', 'ConversionController@evaluateFile' );
```

Is this scenario achievable, or do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it is not good practice to assign the same method to multiple routes, just have one route, in this case, process, be the route to process the file. Second, for what you are looking for, I would recommend using Jquery and [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead. For what you are asking for, I would recommend something along these lines:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '/process',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(){
                      //Loading Animation goes in here, I usually use a 
                      //modal with a loading animation myself
                    },
                    success:function(json){
                        //Use Jquery to modify your page with the results here
                    }
                });
```

Nothing too difficult. I am not sure if you are familiar with Jquery, but it is VERY easy to use and learn. If you are a little more daring/familiar with JSON, you can also switch out the `dataType` to be `json` instead and in the success function parameter, use json data you pass from the controller and modify it how you wish.

Update: When running ajax, you need to ensure that any default actions on your form don't run so that ajax will be able to run uninterrupted. As an example, I will assume you are using a form to upload the file, and I am going to give this form itself an `id="fileupload"`:

```
      $('#fileupload').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //This will take whatever default action 
        //was going to be performed, and stop it from running, in this case, the form submission

//Run Ajax code in here

        });
```

I have also changed the `html` to `json` from my previous post to declare that we are passing json data back into the success function. In order to do that, inside of the controller that is processing the data, you will need to add everything that you want to be passed back into ajax to be added into an array then converted into json, like so:

```
public function processFile(Request $request){

$return = array();
$name = $request->file(name_of_file_field_input)->getClientOriginalName();


if(isset($name) && !empty($name)){
$return['name'] = $name;
}

return json_encode($return);

}
```

Then, inside of the success function, you can take the json parameter and use dot notation to get the name:

```
    success:function(json){
                           alert(json.name);
}
```

You can do whatever you would like with the name, include adding it to a field in your form using Jquery. That part I will leave up to you, but this should at least get you on the way to getting to where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Not too familiar with JQuery, it's on my list to learn.  Quick question though, where does your code sample live?  Within my view or in the controller?  If on the view, how do I attach it to my process button? And is it good practise to mix Laravel and JQuery?

Comment: Okay, I have implemented the jQuery but it is still returning me to a blank page with the JSON data (not my original view). I have also noticed that it doesn't seem to be executing the `success:function(html)` code.

Comment: First question answered, Jquery will be inside of script tags in the view, just like normal Javascript. Second, since you are not too familiar with Jquery, you need to make sure you include Jquery onto your site ( I don't know if you did that already), by either downloading it, or adding a CDN link to it. You can go here to get it: https://jquery.com/download/. I am going to update my answer now that I know that you are not too familiar with Jquery.

Comment: Perfect thankyou! I was on the right track, but couldn't see that my code was failing in my controller and thus passing back an error.  I added an error method on the ajax call to capture the message.  Also, your code snippet kept giving me a 419 response until I followed the details on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status) post.  Thanks again

Comment: Right, forgot to mention needing to add CSRF token to the ajax call...whoops. I have mine added in an Ajax header when the page first loads so I don't have to think about it normally. Glad it's all working out for you. Happy coding!