# Laravel 5 X-CSRF-TOKEN 500 (Internal Server Error) in Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, csrf-protection

Hello I have change password using Ajax (this is a short version of the code):

```
var password = document.querySelector('[name="password"]').value;

    action = 'http://localhost:8012/market2/market2/public/account/query/';

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
    }

    xmlhttp.open("post",action + password, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.getElementById('token-csrf').value);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        if (this.responseText == "false") {
            document.getElementById("error_password").innerHTML = "You actually password is wrong!";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("error_password").innerHTML = "OK";
            return true;
        }

      }
    }


    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

And my csrf-token:
`<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token-csrf" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

I don't know did I correct add parameter `X-CSRF-TOKEN` to my script. First I have error `ajax 419 (unknown status)` so I added `X-CSRF-TOKEN` and now I have error `500 (Internal Server Error)`. I also tried this: [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46466616/6678345)

Edit Post:

Is't my query method:

```
public function queryPass($pass) {

  $user = Auth::user();
  $current_password = $user->password;

  if(Hash::check($pass, $current_password)) {

    $updatePassword = App\User::where('id', $user->id)->update(['password' => bcrypt($pass)]);
    echo "true";

  } else {

    echo "false";
    die;

  }

}
```

And route:

```
Route::get('account/query/{pass?}', 'UsersController@queryPass');
```

Comment: 500  is the status code for server, plz provide the backend code

Comment: Go to `storage/logs/laravel.log` clear the contents of it, then cause the error again, go to `storage/logs/laravel.log` again, copy the code from it, and paste https://paste.laravel.io/ <- there, then include the link in your question

Comment: @MahdiYounesi I edit my post

Comment: Can u include error stack trace so we can find out where the error occurs?

Comment: what do you do in php side ? you get the user new password and then what ?

Comment: @NikolaGavric I've cleared the logs file. Then I called the error, but now the file is EMPTY. Nothing is saved in the logs file

Comment: @MahdiYounesi If the actually password is correct I change password to the new

Comment: If nothing is saved in the `laravel.log` file then the request is not even hitting your `Laravel routes`

Comment: Check that the url you are using is correct

Comment: @NikolaGavric Yes It's correct, because when I chane value of `action` for example: `action = 'http://localhost:8012/market2/market2/public/account/query22222/'` I have error 404 (Not Found)

Comment: maybe there is no authenticated user already

Comment: `laravel.log` would've recorded that error @MahdiYounesi, but it didn't

Comment: @MahdiYounesi It is authenticated, I refresh the page every time

Comment: Seems to me that your request is not even hitting `Laravel` at all, because if it would hit and throw error your `laravel.log` wouldn't  be empty @michal

Comment: @NikolaGavric Maybe you're right, but I do not know why ajax does not connect to the PHP code. Maybe the whole code will tell you something: https://pastebin.com/61pjpsUh

Comment: Does your page refreshes or shows blank when you click `Save`?

Comment: @NikolaGavric No, because I add `return false;` to `onclick`: `{!! Form::open([ 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'onsubmit' => 'checkPassword(); return false;']) !!}`

Comment: instead of `echo` in your controller, use `return "false";` and also change `return "true";` and remove `die`, then try again and tell us did that fix your issue?

Comment: @NikolaGavric No, still I have error 500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164927/discussion-between-nikola-gavric-and-michal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem was that he missed `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;` at the top of his controller, he used `use Hash;`, second thing when we resolved that was that, he was returning a boolean from inside a controller, when he is supposed to return an object which implements `__toString` method or a string, so he returned a correct response in this case a string "true" and "false"

Comment: Thank you again for your help ;)