# POST 419 (unknown status) laravel error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i want to submit my form using ajax following is my javascript

```
$.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
      url: "http://localhost/shago/register/submit",
      data: user_firstname,

      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
});
```

i have included meta tag in form like

```
<div id="individual" class="hid">
<form method="POST" id="individual_form" name="individual_form" action="{{ route('register.submit') }}">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and in controller i have just returned a message but i am getting

POST http://localhost/shago/register/submit 419 (unknown status)

above error can you please help me ,let me know for any other inputs i know it is mostly caused by csrf token 
(i have declared submit route in web.php and also api.php file)

Comment: Show us the controller code for `/shago/register/submit`

Comment: public function submit()
    {
        return "success";
        //print_r($_POST);
    }

Comment: 500 means server fault why are you looking for the error in you client side code ? provide the backend error

Comment: i am running on localhost

Comment: 500 means php error ,  an error in your controller

Comment: son its wrong in csrf token its caused by that

Comment: Check your error logs in `/storage/logs` to see if it gives any hints there.

Comment: checked now its giving 419 (unknown status)

Comment: @aynber Thanks for your comments!! I found it's caused by another issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  headers: {
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
  url: "http://localhost/shago/register/submit",
  data: {// change data to this object
     _token : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 
     user_firstname:user_firstname
  }
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code to your master file

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the meta tag in head section

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

2) Set header in ajax , like

```
header:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
```

3) Send CSRF token with data

```
     data:({_token : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 
name:name,category:category}),
```

or CSRF token can be written as

```
 "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
```