# File upload with fetch API vuejs returns 419 unknown status

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fetch

I am using VUE.js with Laravel to upload file using fetch api. I have added the csrf token to the header of the request, but still getting the 419 unknown status. Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Here is the JS of the component

```
<script>
    export default {
        name:'UploadModal',
        data(){
            return {
                image:'',
                ext:'',
                file:''
            };
        },
        methods: {
            onFileChange(e) {
                var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.file = files[0];
                this.createImage(files[0]);
            },
            uploadArtwork: function () {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('artwork', this.file);
                fetch(this.$parent.itemUrl, {
                    method:'POST',
                    body: formData,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : Laravel.csrfToken
                    }
                })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(res => {
                        alert(res);
                    })
                    .catch(e => console.log(e));
            },
            createImage(file) {
                var image = new Image();
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var vm = this;

                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    vm.image = e.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status

Comment: please check the code I have added the csrf_token to header but its not working

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into this issue as well when using `fetch` and the linked answer ([Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)) did not help, since that relates to jQuery's Ajax method.

For those who are facing the same issue, it looks like this is due to the default `credentials` setting (defaults to "omit"), which essentially omits the csrf header for some reason. You can get around this by changing `credentials` to "same-origin" or "include" depending on your needs.

Example:

```
fetch("/leads", {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: csrf_header
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (json) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json.leads.data,
                sort: json.sort,
                search: json.search,
                sort_by: json.sort_by,
                filter: json.filter
            });
        }
    );
```