# Laravel Ajax 419 Error on Production but not Local Development and Nothing In /storage/logs/laravel.log

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

So I've run into this issue where I'm having a 419 Error code when submitting my AJAX request through my project. I know that this error is due to the CSRF Token not being passed, or not valid.

Story behind this: I've created a "maintenance mode" on my project. This maintenance mode restricts access to the front end by displaying the 503 error page, but still allows my administrators access to the backend to update the site, etc. This is done using some middleware. See the code here on my github page for more information on how I accomplish this functionality.

https://github.com/JDsWebService/ModelAWiki/commit/263a59ebba42688d4a232a5838334b9ee419504c

So maybe this is an issue with the 503 error page on my production environment? I'm not too sure.

I've taken a look at this Question and Answer on SOF, but it doesnt seem to be helping me any.

[Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Here is the production site, take a look at the console for more information: http://modelawiki.com/

Here is my code pertaining to the 419 error:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // CSRF Ajax Token
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });



    // Add Section Post Button
    $('#subscribeButton').click(function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */

        // Clear Feedback Boxes
        $('#valid-feedback').css("display", "none");
        $('#invalid-feedback').css("display", "none");
        // Input Field  
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

        console.log(email);
        console.log(token);
        // Post
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/email/subscribe/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                email: email,
                "_token": token,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // Check Server Side validation
                if($.isEmptyObject(data.errors)){
                    // Show the Feedback Div
                    $('#valid-feedback').css("display", "block");
                    // Add the Bootsrapt Is Invalid Class
                    $('#email').addClass('is-valid');
                    // Validation Failed Display Error Message
                    $('#valid-feedback').text(data['success']);
                    // Animate the Object
                    $('#email').animateCss('tada', function() {});

                    console.log(data['success']);
                }else{
                    // Show the Feedback Div
                    $('#invalid-feedback').css("display", "block");
                    // Add the Bootsrapt Is Invalid Class
                    $('#email').addClass('is-invalid');
                    // Validation Failed Display Error Message
                    $('#invalid-feedback').text(data.errors[0]);

                    // Animate the Object
                    $('#email').animateCss('shake', function() {});

                    console.log(data.errors);
                }

            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }); // End Ajax POST function

    }); // End Click Event

    // On Focus of the Email Box
    $('#email').focus(function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */
        $('#valid-feedback').css("display", "none");
        $('#invalid-feedback').css("display", "none");
    });

}); // End Document Ready
```

**HTML Form**

```
<div class="input-group input-group-newsletter">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email..." aria-label="Enter email..." aria-describedby="basic-addon" id="email">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="subscribeButton">Notify Me!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="invalid-feedback" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
    <div id="valid-feedback" class="valid-feedback"></div>
</div>
```

**Header** (This shows that the CSRF token is actually on the 503 error page)

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Again, this code works on my local environment, but not on my production environment. (I also know that AJAX requests can and are being handled in other parts of my site just fine on the production environment, so I know it's not a server issue and has to do with code)

Just in case here is my controller code as well.

```
// Store the Email into the database
public function subscribe(Request $request) {

    // Validate the request
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:email_subscribers,email',
    ]);

    // If the validation fails
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => $validator->errors()->all(),
        ]);
    }

    // New Section Object
    $subscription = new EmailSubscription;

    // Add Name into Section Object
    $subscription->email = $request->email;

    // Save the Section
    $subscription->save();

    // Return The Request
    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'You have successfully subscribed! Check your email!'
    ]);
}
```

And my route

```
// Email Routes
Route::prefix('email')->group(function() {

    // Create Post Route for subscribing
    Route::post('/subscribe', 'EmailSubscriptionsController@subscribe')->name('email.subscribe');

});
```

Comment: Check your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file. That should contain an actual stack trace of the error.

Comment: Log file is empty. The log file does display errors though as when I was setting up the project on the server I was getting Database errors and such before I ran my migrations, etc... Heres the terminal view: https://imgur.com/a/bly6LIg

Comment: How exactly did you determine that the error is due to an invalid CSRF token?

Comment: And silly question, but, did you refresh the main page? The CSRF token will eventually expire, after about 15 minutes or so.

Comment: I only am assuming that its a CSRF issue because thats what most 419 error codes are... or at least thats what pops up when i use ol' wonderful google. Yes... lol I have refreshed the page. No question too silly.

Comment: It is weird though that the log is empty but it's throwing the 419 code.... Hmmm....

Comment: What does `data.errors` contain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177399/discussion-between-j-robinson-and-mike).

Comment: Permissions on storage or log file since file is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it can help someone, we experienced the same issue and it was due to a server space disk issue. Therefore, Laravel was unable to write files (sessions.php notably).