# Laravel Basic AJAX Request Not Working?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel as My FrameWork, and stunned when try to using AJAX Request using Laravel. As all my code was below here :

Route ( Laravel )

```
/*-- Welcome Page Handler --*/
Route::get('/{pages}', 'UsersController@project' );
Route::get('/', 'UsersController@project' );
```

Controller ( Laravel )

```
public function project( Request $request, $pages = 'index' ) { 

    ... authetication section ...

    if( $getAccess ) { 
        define( "REALNAME"  , $getAccess->realname );
        define( "PERMISSION" , $getAccess->permission );
        define( "CABANG"    , $getAccess->cabang );
        define( "COMPANY"   , $getAccess->company );

        return view( 'index' , [ 
            'pages' => $pages , 
            'params' => 'main' , 
            'title' => ucwords( $pages ) , 
            'headertitle' => 'Easy CRM' , 
            'request' => $request
        ] );
    } else { 
        return view( 'login' , [ 
            'title' => 'Login' , 
            'headertitle' => 'Easy CRM'
        ] );
    }

}
```

Javascript Section ( inside  section )

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax_save',
            data: {text:$('#txt').val()},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
                $("#hasil").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML Section

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" id="txt" name="text" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <span id="text1">Result Maybe Here</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button>Get External Content</button>
</div>
```

All i can do was this, and the result is freeze, nothing happen. The case is simple, show what user type below ( id text1 ).

**Update 1 :**

```
<script src="http://{{ SERVERNAME }}/libraries/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://{{ SERVERNAME }}/libraries/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://{{ SERVERNAME }}/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax_save',
            data: {text:$('#txt').val()},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
                $("#hasil").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Error Code 419 (unknown status)

**Update 2 :**

```
<script src="http://{{ SERVERNAME }}/libraries/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://{{ SERVERNAME }}/libraries/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://{{ SERVERNAME }}/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://{{ SERVERNAME }}/rajawali/js/ajax-request.min.js"></script>
```

ajax-request.min.js

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#password").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax_save',
            data: {text:$('#username').val()},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
                $("#hasil").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

All update still make same result Error Code 419 (Unknown Status), since Laravel using CSRF Protection, and how to passed this or maybe something ???

Comment: Hello, what does the browser console say any specific error? Thus why did you use get instead of post it seems to me that you are trying to post some data. Furthermore there is not a route to this url ajax_save which you call in your ajax.

Comment: This was the route to "Route::get('/{pages}', 'UsersController@project' );" ajax_save #ByLaravelWay or maybe there are some other ways

Comment: You need to add which error you're getting...

Comment: @OzanKurt the error is nothing happen, when user click on button

Comment: So you don't get an error in the console or network tab? Can you show the route for `ajax_save` and the controller method that goes with it?

Comment: Last error found now was Error Code 419 (Unknown Status)

Comment: Try using **url: '/ajax_save',** for the url.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status

Comment: @Wreigh same result Error Code 419 (Unknown Status)

Comment: "This was the route to "Route::get('/{pages}', 'UsersController@project' );" ajax_save" --> I've never read such thing in the doc. Where do you get this reference? AFAIK there isn't such route by default in laravel. Have you tried using `url: '/'` instead?

Comment: @YohanesGultom What do you think with `url: '/'` meaning ?