# Laravel Controller@update function

Tags: laravel, forms, post, put

So, I'm trying to send my new stats to the update function in my CharactersController, but it say this error: 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException'.I tried method spoofing, but that didn't work.

Here is my index where I want to edit the character($tet is a row function of my character that I'm watching):

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['CharactersController@update', $tet->id], 'method' => 'POST','id'=>'form1', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<tr>
<td>HP:</td>
<td>{{$tet->hp}}</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addValue(1)">+</button></td>
<td><p>-></p></td>
<td><input id="jedna" class="edit" name="hodnota" type="number" disabled="true" value={{$tet->hp}}></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ATTACK:</td>
<td>{{$tet->attack}}</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addValue(2)">+</button></td>
<td><p>-></p></td>
<td><input id="dva" class="edit" name="hodnota" type="number" disabled="true" value={{$tet->attack}}></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>LUCK:</td>
<td>{{$tet->luck}}</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addValue(3)">+</button></td>
<td><p>-></p></td>
<td><input id="tri" class="edit" name="hodnota" type="number" disabled="true" value={{$tet->luck}}></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AGILITY:</td>
<td>{{$tet->agility}}</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addValue(4)">+</button></td>
<td><p>-></p></td>
<td><input id="ctyri" class="edit" name="hodnota" type="number" disabled="true" value={{$tet->agility}}></td>
</tr>
<button onclick="uloz()">SAVE ALL</button>
{{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

In the 'uloz()' function is that I enable all number inputs and submit the form.
This is my CharactersContrller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $character = Character::find($id);
    $character->hp=$request->input('jedna');
    $character->attack=$request->input('dva');
    $character->luck=$request->input('tri');
    $character->agility=$request->input('ctyri');
    $character->save();
    return redirect('/character');

}
```

Comment: Please show your route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I got it, be careful on your HTML structure, I had my form inside the `<table>`, but it has to be outside. That was all, no CSRF token needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Your view file like this**:

```
{!! Form::model($tet, ['route' => ['characters.update', $tet->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
```

**Your route like this**:

```
Route::post('characters/update/{id}', 'CharactersController@update')->name('characters.update');
```

**Updated Answer**

Please add `CSRF` token in your form like:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**Add csrf token in ajax**:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Comment: That threw error 419, 'Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.'

Comment: @JiříZajíček: May be your session is expire please refresh and try

Comment: I restarted xampp, but it is still same, in the page that says that the session is expired, the Chrome-Network in General say this Request Method: POST
Status Code: 419 unknown status

Comment: @JiříZajíček: Please review this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status/46466616) may be useful for you

Comment: Add csrf token to form

Comment: So this didn't help neither, still the same site. (Idk if it helps but the url on that site is :sitename.test/characters/update/1)
In the Chrome network is this-
Request URL: http://zjgame.test/characters/update/1
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 419 unknown status
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade