# Unable to make POST request using FETCH

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, fetch

I am trying to make a POST request using FETCH but I am getting this error - 
`419 (unknown status)`

This is my code:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "post", headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: {_token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}',
   }
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
```

I have also added `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in the head section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status

Comment: Please post the server side code relevant to this request. You should also provide the names and versions of the technologies you are using.

Comment: The mentioned duplicate has several possible reasons and fixes, please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Answer (score 0):

For start, if you send `Content-Type': 'application/json'`, you should `JSON.stringify` the request body.

As for 419 error code, it probably means `Authentication timeout` ([source](https://getstatuscode.com/419)), but since it's not standartized, your browser might not recognize it.