# Login to laravel website from another website on same domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, http

Website A - simple php form
Website B - Laravel website

On Website A I have a website

This is the function on website A that grabs a valid token from website B

```
function getAuthToken() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://B.website.test',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var csfr = $(response).filter('meta[name="csrf-token"]').prop('content');
            var token = $(response).find('input[name="_token"]').val();
            $('input[name="_token"]').val(token);
            $('input[name="csrf-token"]').val(csfr);
        },
        error: function () {
            //
        }
    });
}
```

This is the function that is supposed to do the login:

```
function doLogin() {
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    var password = $('input[name="password"]').val();

    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
    var cookieName = 'XSRF-TOKEN';

    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + _token + ";expires=" + myDate
        + ";domain=.website.test;path=/";

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'XSRF-TOKEN': _token
        },
        url: 'http://B.website.test/doLogin',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"_token": _token, "email": email, "password": password},
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            //
        }
    });
```

The last piece of js:

```
$('#websiteb-login').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doLogin();
});
```

All I get in response over the Network tab is 419 status.
Any help ? :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status see this question, you might get some idea.

Comment: are you getting response by postman?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you should ensure:

You need to make sure your AJAX request actually sends the cookies by using the option:

```
  $.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://B.website.test/doLogin',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"_token": _token, "email": email, "password": password},
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function () {
        //
    },
    xhrFields: {  withCredentials: true }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set your document domain to be the base domain, for example:

```
 document.domain = 'website.test';
```

This *should* ensure all requests to subdomains of website.test do not trigger CORS policies (and possibly also send cookies automatically).

The `XSRF-TOKEN` header/cookie is encrypted so you can't use them to send the token. Just keep the `_token` data field as you currently are.

Comment: Does the request happen at all? Are there any errors?