# Laravel post - 419 unknown status

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to use [this package](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-beautiful-vue-component-for-image-cropping-and-uploading/), which does everything I want. So indeed everything seems to work except for when I upload my image.
It's not going to UtilsController@uploadfile function at all.

```
Route::post('/uploadfile', 'UtilsController@uploadfile');



public function uploadfile(Request $request){
        $img = $request->img;
        $newlocation = $request->newlocation;
        $filename = $request->filename;

        return file_put_contents ($newlocation . "/" . $filename , $img );
    }
```

But when I inspect the network, everything seems to be OK...

[image]

[image]

And I get this error: 419 unknown status

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like CSRF. In the request headers is there a csrf token? The library you're using has a section for headers using vue2 you can drop it in the same way you would ajax like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was it!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there may be situations where on which we may want to have routes to exist without requiring the CSRF_TOKEN. We can simply add those URIs or routes in VerifyCsrfToken middleware's except array like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
 /**
  * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
  *
  * @var array
  */
 protected $except = [
  'stripe/*',
  'http://example.com/foo/bar',
  'http://example.com/foo/*',
 ];
}
```

Comment: Great, that's useful!