# JQuery preventDefault not stopping page from reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I have a form in my html page and for some reason with the jquery command it won't stop reloading the page. I've tried removing the post method adding `javscript:void(0)`. Changed

```
$('like_unlike').submit(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
});
```

to

```
$('like_unlike').on("submit", function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
});
```

I don't understand I can't get the form to send a post request to my php side without relaoding the page. I'm using ajax to send a post request but either the page "sends" and changes the page to expired or nothing happens.

Here is my HTML

```
<form id="like_unlike">
    <input type="hidden" name="art" value="{{ $arts[$i]->id }}">
    <input type="image" onclick="likeButton()" class="article-like pl-2 float-right" src="{{ asset('/images/unliked.svg') }}" alt="" id="unlike">
    <input type="image" onclick="unlikeButton()" class="article-like pl-2 float-right" src="{{ asset('/images/like.svg') }}" alt="" id="like">
</form>
```

I'm using Laravel 5.8

Comment: The selector is `#like_unlike`.

Comment: But why am i getting a 419 error saying unknown status

Comment: Looks like a [csrf token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status/47966714) issue

Comment: How would I fix this