# How to get response from Jquery Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, response

I wanna get the response result from ajax request, when I click a button with value "Accept" to send server.
Thank you for help.

I get the error 419 *POST http://localhost:8000/posts/list_post_ajax 419 (unknown status)*

- View:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th>Post ID</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>Name User</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Datetime</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Accept</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($posts as $row)
            <tr id="{{ $row->post_id }}"> 
                <td>{{$row->post_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->user_id}}</td>
                <th>{{$row->users->name}}</th>
                <td>{{$row->post_title}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->post_content}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->post_datetime}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->post_status}}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success accept-btn" data-postID="{{$row->post_id}}">Accept</button>
            </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
</table>
```

- Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('.accept-btn').click(function(){
            var postId = $(this).attr('data-postID');
            console.log(postId)

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{route('posts.list_post_ajax')}}",      
                data: { postId: postId },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success :function(response) {
                    alert("thank u");
                },
            });

        })
    });
</script>
```

-- Route:

```
Route::post('/list_post_ajax','PostController@list_post_ajax')->name('posts.list_post_ajax');
```

- Controller:

```
public function list_post_ajax()
    {
       return response()->json('success');
    }
```

Comment: You get error 419 because you send a request without csrf token to an url that is protected by csrf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Comment: Yes, I have fixed that problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send CSRF token in your post request. So set up the ajax fist like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

And Send the Request now

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{route('posts.list_post_ajax')}}",      
        data: { postId: postId },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success :function(response) {
            alert("thank u");
        },
    });
```

Set the meta tag in your `<head>`

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Yes, I have fixed that problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

send also the token 
data : {postId:postId,_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}' }

Comment: Yes, I have fixed that problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `csrf-token`.

You can read about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Long story short: you have 3 ways of solving this:

**1. Fix it globally:**

Add this to your ajax setup (so it's executed on every page in your project):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

and add this to your main layout:

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

and you will have that ready on every request from now on..

**2. fix it just for current endpoint:**

add `_token` to payload of your request:

```
data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "id": id
}
```

**3. or exclude your route from the middleware that is blocking it (it's probably `VerifyCSRF`):**

```
protected $except = [
        'route/*',
    ];
```

Comment: Yes, I have fixed that problem. Thank you so much