# Ajax post in Laravel always throws an error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, post

I am trying to make a POST request with ajax from my view to a PHP controller and I have all the data ready but never makes the post always throws error and I don't know why.

PS: I'm not very skilled at AJAX

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnComp', function () {

    var weeks = [];
    var pId = $('#proyid').val();
    weeks.push(pId);

    $('.2').each(function () {
        weeks.push($(this).text());
    });

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault(e);
    $.ajax({
        url: host + "/projectsVar",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            weeks: weeks
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

This is the view

```html
{!!Form::open(['action' => 'projectsController@projectsVar', 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<table class="table table-sm text-center">
    @php
    $j = 1;
    @endphp
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= 13; ++$i) <tr>
        @for ($j = $j; $j <= 4*$i; ++$j) <td class="1" onclick="changeColor(this, {{ $j }})"
            style="background-color:; color: black;">{{ $j }}</td>
            @endfor
            </tr>
            @endfor
</table>
<div class="container text-center">
    <h4>Por favor seleccione las semanas a comparar y luego presione</h4>
    <a href="#" class='btn btn-info btnComp'>Comparar</a>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Update: This is the error:

> POST http://localhost:8000/projectsVar 419 (unknown status)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please do include the error you're getting so we can tell what's going on and try to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Comment: Try this instead `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)