# 419 status response on ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to send ajax request with form data in which is append only one file. The rest of the data is send with the same ajax request but within other field.

```
let input = $('#to_id').val();
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file-upload', $("input[name='fileUpload']").prop('files')[0]);

            //Tried with and without this row
            data.append('_token', '<?php echo csrf_token();?>');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/message/data",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: {
                    _token: '<?php echo csrf_token();?>',
                    girlname: input,
                    uploadFile: data
                },
                dataType: "json",
//More code here
```

What I get as response is:

```
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"
file: "/home/g2cu6o1a/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php"
line: 203
message: ""
```

The response status is 419.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Comment: Nope. This one doesn't.