# PostsController@store not working when trying to create a post

Tags: laravel

This is my section and I want to send the form to the store function in the PostsController but when I hit submit it shows a 419 page expired however it should return to the posts page and the post should be stored in the database.

```
@section('content')
    <form action="{{ action('PostsController@store') }}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Body</label>
            <textarea id="body" name="body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

and this is my store function in the PostsController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //create post
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/posts');
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **419 page expired** error generally comes from a csrf token issue.

Try adding `@csrf` within your form:

```
<form action="{{ action('PostsController@store') }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   // etc
</form>
```