# Ajax call via js file to laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax call from a js file that sends values as a post where I need to get those values and insert them in the database, I was going to a php file called burn.php and it worked normally but the need arose to use session in laravel so I think that I will need to start sending to a laravel route.
But when it is sent to the route in the controller it is not receiving the information from the ajax call to insert in the bank.

ajax.js

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if( xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200 ){
        console.log( xml.responseText );
      }
    };

    xml.open("POST", "points", true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xml.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
    xml.send("points=" + window.points + "&level=" + window.level);
```

route/web.php

```
Route::post('/points', 'HomeController@pontos')->name('points');
```

HomeController.php

```
public function points(Request $request)
    {
        $value = $request->get('points');
        $level = $request->get('level');
        $user = Session::get('user_id');

        DB::table('blo_record')->insert(
            ['id_user' => $user, 'id_step' => $level, 'points' => $value, 'attempts' => 1]
        );
    }
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

My system is in laravel because of that I have a session that is necessary to use through the controller, but the call needed me to do an action that executes the function of the controller, and insert the data in the database.
this code today is not doing any action because the value points are not being found.

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console to see what data is being sent in the request. Also, how are you triggering the AJAX call?

Comment: When I consulted the browser network on the points call, there was the following error:       Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/blockly/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117    with return of 405 method not allowed.

Comment: Ah right, that's because your route only handles GET (from `Route::get('/points', ...`) but you are trying to POST

Comment: changed to Route::post('/pontos', 'HomeController@points')->name('points'); but now the error is code 419 unknown status

Comment: [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Comment: Send csrf token along with the post data.

Comment: I insert token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content; and xml.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token); in file js. And <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" /> in blade.php but not working.

Comment: is returning null value.

Comment: Well what do you expect? Your `points` method doesn't return any response

Comment: The points returns yes, who does not return is the csrf in the variable token.

Comment: @Phil Thank's,working. changed Token for var token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

Comment: @Phil make an answer to my question for me to mark as resolved, so you get a deserved score because I got it solution with your help.

Comment: Better to close as a duplicate. Give your points to that question and its answers