# Laravel 419 Error - VerifyCsrfToken issue when using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm reaching Laravel 419 error while using Ajax and I don't have any idea about what is causing this.

I saw on other posts it has to do something with `csrf token`, but I have no form so I don't know how to fix this.

**My code:**

```
function check_login_auth(id) {
    var email_address = $("input[name=l_email_address]").val();
    var password = $("input[name=l_password]").val();
    var token = $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseurl+"route",
            data: {
                email:email_address,
                password:password,
                _token:token
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#l_loading_gif').show()
                $('#l_login_form').hide()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // console.log(data)
            },
        });
    } else {
        $('#s_error').append('<p style="color: red">something went wrong.</p>')
    }
}
```

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: `_token:token` should have been enough assuming your token is in the specified meta tag. Try checking the initial server response for the session cookie (the name should be stated in `config/sessions.php` and then check if the cookie being sent by the AJAX request is the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Comment: no its also not working for me _token:{{ csrf_token() }}... santax error show

Answer (score 1):

You are calling POST method so You need to pass `csrf_token` in headers.

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
},
```

Your ajax looks like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseurl+"route",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    data: {
        email:email_address,
        password:password,
        _token:token
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#l_loading_gif').show()
        $('#l_login_form').hide()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // console.log(data)
    },
});
```

If you're calling it in js file then pass the csrf token in meta tag.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And headers like

```
headers: 
{
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

Comment: are you using ajax in js file?

Comment: error 419: "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",

Comment: yes first i use meta but still not working then i move  header: X-CSRF-TOKEN

Comment: its laravel project

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the `csrf-token` value in proper way

```
var CSRF_TOKEN          = document.getElementById("csrf_token").value;

<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

or

```
var CSRF_TOKEN          = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

or

```
var CSRF_TOKEN          = form.find("input[name='_token']").val();

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then you have to pass this data in

```
data: {
        email:email_address,
        password:password,
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN
    },
```

Comment: Do you have `csrf_token` value in your ajax request value

Answer (score 0):

When you are making post requests to laravel it expects a csrf token to protect your requests even if you do not use form. I suggest you to switch to axios since it is easily configurable.

with axios you can do something like this

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = 'your token here';
axios.post('/url', {
firstName: 'something',
lastName: 'something'})
```