# exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException" "CSRF token mismatch." 419 unknown status

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I am using **laravel 8 sunctumns SPA** frontend on **React.**

error is **mismatch token error 419** unknown Status

i tired to solve this issue

ENV

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000

SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost:8000
```

CORS.php

```
 'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'register'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*' , "localhost:3000"],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

React-redux

```
 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
      apiClient.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          apiClient.post('/login', {
              email: user.username,
              password: user.password
          }).then(response => {
              console.log(response)
              localStorage.setItem("loggedIn" , "true")
          }).catch(error => console.log(error))
      })
```

APIClient

```
const baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `laravel 8 sunctumns SPA` token based or cookies .?  and try  `apiClient.post('/api/login',` not `/login` it should be `/api/login`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)

Comment: @KamleshPaul thanks for your reply i am using web.php route using sunctums                        i am follw this link https://laravel-news.com/using-sanctum-to-authenticate-a-react-spa

Comment: @BilalSheikh check in that article they mentioned `"Add this to the routes/api.php file:" `  normal `web.php` have csrf protection by default so your getting `419` error

Comment: @KamleshPaul i am using login routes in sunctums use default login routes please check this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: can you try once `apiClient.post('/login', {` to `apiClient.post('/api/login', {`   https://medium.com/@godilite/using-laravel-airlock-with-vuejs-1d343ee6f10

Comment: @BilalSheikh great