# Adding csrf input to tinyMCE image upload Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, post, tinymce

I want to add `@csrf` to the request of the tinyMCE image upload because it returns error 419
NOTE: this is not in a script tag, this is separated JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
        ...
        relative_urls: false,
        paste_data_images: true,
        image_title: true,
        automatic_uploads: true,
        images_upload_url: "/admin/uploadImg/",
        file_picker_types: "image",
        // override default upload handler to simulate successful upload
        file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "file");
            input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
            input.onchange = function() {
                var file = this.files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = function() {
                    var id = "blobid" + new Date().getTime();
                    var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(",")[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                };
            };
            input.click();
        }
    });
});
```

I modified it to, but it still giving me back `(failed to upload image: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then'))`
and in console log: `failed to upload image: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#body',
        plugins: '...',
        toolbar: '...',
        toolbar_mode: 'floating',
        tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
        relative_urls: false,
        paste_data_images: true,
        image_title: true,
        automatic_uploads: true,
        file_picker_types: "image",
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            var xhr, formData;

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', '/admin/uploadImg/');

            xhr.onload = function () {
                var json;

                if (xhr.status != 200) {
                    console.log('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    return;
                }

                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                    console.log('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    return;
                }

                success(json.location);
            };

            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
            // append CSRF token in the form data
            formData.append('_token', $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content'));

            xhr.send(formData);
        },
        // override default upload handler to simulate successful upload
        file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "file");
            input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
            input.onchange = function () {
                var file = this.files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    var id = "blobid" + new Date().getTime();
                    var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(",")[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                };
            };
            input.click();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, it's been a while but have you been able to find a solution? I have, basically, the same problem and still getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status)